# Custom View not inflating when using WindowManager in service

Tags: android, service, android-custom-view, android-windowmanager

I am trying to add a custom KnockView using WindowManager in service. Here is KnockView class.

```
    public class KnowView extends LinearLayout {
    public KnowView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public KnowView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.KnowView);
        try {
            isFromChangeKnock = typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.KnowView_changeKnock, false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle();
        }
        initView();
    }

    public KnowView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initView();
    }
     private void initView() {
        mainLayout = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.knock_code, this);
    }

}
```

So basically in KnowView class we are inflating another layout (knock_code) and adding that into KnowView. And after that, I am using this custom Knockview in another layout called. `main_view.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <production.kado.lock.views.KnowView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        app:changeKnock="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and inflating `main_view.xml`in service with WindowManager like this.

```
WindowManager windowManager = ((WindowManager) 
this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE));

View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.main_view, null);
windowManager.addView(mainView, getViewParam(true));
```

But I am getting these exceptions when I run this service.

```
07-12 09:16:34.087 12020-12020/production.kado.lock E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: production.kado.lock, PID: 12020
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service production.kado.lock.services.LockService: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3252)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1594)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class <unknown>
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class <unknown>
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:21008)
    at production.kado.lock.views.KnowView.findAllViews(KnowView.java:115)
    at production.kado.lock.views.KnowView.initView(KnowView.java:99)
    at production.kado.lock.views.KnowView.<init>(KnowView.java:46)
    at production.kado.lock.services.LockService.addLockView(LockService.java:87)
    at production.kado.lock.services.LockService.onCreate(LockService.java:69)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3242)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1594)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 35: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f02012d a=-1}
```

I also used KnockView in activity but in activity, it works fine. The only problem is when used in service with WindowManager.

Comment: what is `KnowView#findAllViews`?

Comment: Actually, find all views a method in which I am finding all view and this line is in findAllViews.
        `mainLayout = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.knock_code, this);`

Comment: no, its inside `private void initView()`

Comment: I just simplified it and wrote here inside initView();

Comment: what is line #47 of `layout/knock_code.xml`?

Comment: @pskink please see my answer below your hint for line  #47 solved my problem but what if i want to use this property in my layout?

Comment: @pskink Thanks that solved my problem can you answer so I can accept?

Comment: `"but what if i want to use this property in my layout?"` you can use `android:background` property, you have the  problem with getting the theme's attribute: `?selectableItemBackground`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem I was using this

```
android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
```

property in my layout button after removing this it's working fine